# $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\beta dx}{1+x^\alpha \sin^2x} , \alpha >\beta>0$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Discuss the convergence or divergence of $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\beta dx}{1+x^\alpha \sin^2x} , \alpha >\beta>0$$

I can see that it will be convergent in $[0,K], K\in \mathbf{R}$ as its upper bounded by its numerator function. But not sure how to proceed for $(K, \infty) $ as the denominator will repeatedly come closer to $1$ thus overall fraction will be closer to numerator function, which is divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha\le1+\beta$, then
$$
\frac{x^\beta }{1+x^\alpha \sin^2x}\ge x^{\beta-\alpha}
$$
for large $x$ and the integral diverges. What happens if $\alpha>1+\beta$? Near the points where $\sin x$ vanishes, the integrand is large. So we estimate the integral on intervals $[k\,\pi,k\,\pi+\epsilon]$ for $k\in\Bbb N$ and small $\epsilon>0$.
\begin{align}
\int_{k\pi}^{k\pi+\epsilon}\frac{x^\beta\,dx}{1+x^\alpha \sin^2x}&\ge\epsilon\,\frac{(k\,\pi)^\beta}{1+(k\,\pi+\epsilon)^\alpha\sin^2\epsilon}\\
&\ge C\,\epsilon\,\frac{k^\beta}{1+k^\alpha\,\epsilon^2}
\end{align}
for some constant $C>0$ independent of $k$ and $\epsilon$. Now choose $\epsilon=k^{-\gamma}$ for an appropriate $\gamma>0$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Few questions- 1st ineq comes basically by assuming $x^\alpha \ge 1+ x^\alpha \sin^2x$ which is not strictly true but I can see that for large $x$, $2x^\alpha \ge 1+ x^\alpha \sin^2x$ is true and therefore your argument works. In second inequality, you are basically suggesting to choose $\beta -\gamma > \alpha -2\gamma \iff \gamma > \alpha-\beta$. Then the integral diverges. However, how did you arrive at last inequality from previous step as we can only concluse $\geq C\epsilon \frac{k^\beta}{1+k^\alpha\epsilon^2(1+\frac{\epsilon}{k\pi})^\alpha}$

Comment: For the first question, you are right, and I have edited my answer. As for the second, you can safely assume $1+\epsilon/(k\,\pi)\le2$. You can keep the $2^\alpha$ in the denominator, or change it to one choosing a smaller $C$.